# Unresolved External Symbol for definitions with DATA in .def file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ffmpeg, linker

I'm trying to use ffmpeg libraries in a VC++ project. I added all the lib files and the headers and set up the properties for the compiler/linker including the .def file for the externals. All the libs/headers/defs come directly from ffmpeg windows 64bit builds. After all that I get errors like:

```
1>exports.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pp_help
1>exports.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol swr_ffversion
1>exports.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sws_context_class
```

All of the definitions that are failing have a DATA keyword following them.
There are a total of 37 of them and all have the DATA keyword....

I'm new to the VS Compiler/Linker and I might have simply missed something. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you define them in exports? You need to use exports.def only when you export something [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx). For ex. if you develop your own library.

Here you don't need to specify it in exports. You need to correctly link the lib and include headers.

The errors appear, because linker can't find the exported functions definitions. It thinks that you have declared and implemented those functions somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I got confused with the exports. I don't have to add it, instead I have to add the DLLs for ffmpeg from the shared build.